# how to find the nearest date in an array?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, luxon

I have an array of dates.

```
['2023-06-02T00:00:00.000+03:00','2023-06-02T00:00:00.000+03:00','2023-12-04T00:00:00.000+03:00']
```

I need that when switching in the date component, I compare the selected date with the given array and give the nearest date if I switched to the right or left
I started making a method. But I don’t understand how to compare this in a cycle

to the left - the date is less, to the right - the date is more

```
 const dateSwitch = (prev: boolean) => {
    let newDate: string = DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date()).startOf("day")
    if (enabledDates.value.length) {
      if (prev) enabledDates.value.forEach((enableDateFromArr,idx) => {
        const enableDate = DateTime.fromISO(enableDateFromArr).startOf("day").toISO()
        const compare = enableDate >= date.value
      }) 
    } 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the selected date and the dates in the array using the `DateTime.fromISO()`. Then, iterate over the array of dates and calculate the difference between each date and the selected date. Using `reduce()`, find the index of the date with the smallest difference and return the date at the index with the smallest difference.

```
const dateSwitch = (prev: boolean) => {
 let newDate: string = DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date()).startOf("day").toISO();
 if (enabledDates.value.length) {
   let selectedDate = DateTime.fromISO(newDate);
   let dates = enabledDates.value.map(date => DateTime.fromISO(date));
   let differences = dates.map(date => selectedDate.diff(date, 'days').days);
   let minIndex = differences.reduce((minIndex, diff, index) => diff < differences[minIndex] ? index : minIndex, 0);
   return dates[minIndex].toISO();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function in JavaScript that takes an array of ISO date strings and a selected date, and returns the nearest date to the selected date :

```js
function getNearestDate(dates, selectedDate) {
  let nearestDate = dates[0];
  let nearestDiff = Math.abs(new Date(dates[0]).getTime() - new Date(selectedDate).getTime());

  for (let i = 1; i < dates.length; i++) {
    const diff = Math.abs(new Date(dates[i]).getTime() - new Date(selectedDate).getTime());
    if (diff < nearestDiff) {
      nearestDiff = diff;
      nearestDate = dates[i];
    }
  }

  return nearestDate;
}

const dates = ['2023-12-22T00:00:00Z', '2024-01-29T00:00:00Z', '2024-02-19T00:00:00Z'];
const selectedDate = '2024-01-01T00:00:00Z';
const nearestDate = getNearestDate(dates, selectedDate);
console.log(nearestDate); // Outputs: '2023-12-22T00:00:00Z'
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const allDates = ['2023-06-02T00:00:00.000+03:00','2023-06-02T00:00:00.000+03:00','2023-12-04T00:00:00.000+03:00']
const searchDate = '2023-10-03T00:00:00.000+03:00'
const tsDates = allDates.map((e) => {
    return { "ts":Date.parse(e), "date": e, "diff": Math.abs(Date.parse(e) - Date.parse(searchDate))}
}).sort((a, b) => a.diff - b.diff)

console.log(tsDates)
//Nearest will be the first one in the Array
console.log(`Nearest date of ${searchDate} is: ${tsDates[0].date}`)
```